# Short story identification - man in contact with his parallel world counterparts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

Science fiction short story, I think it appeared in the 1990s/2000s.

It is about a person who manages to contact hundreds and hundreds of his counterparts in parallel worlds, and in the story is hosting a sort of phone-in for his alternates (IIRC).

I have a vague feeling that might have been by Robert Reed, and might have first appeared in *Interzone* magazine.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but it reminded me of https://uncannymagazine.com/article/and-then-there-were-n-one/ which is an excellent story about the same person from multiple parallel universes getting together at a con.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the story you are thinking of is "Frank" by Robert Reed, which was indeed published in Interzone, issue number 154 (April 2000), and which can be read online at the Internet Archive ([link](https://archive.org/details/interzone-154-2000-04-bogof-39/page/n19/mode/2up)).

Blurb:

> The multiverse is infinite, and that infinity is populated with an
> infinite number of Franks. A very specific Frank. And it so happens
> that one of these Franks is very successful, and also very willing to
> shout across the multiverse to the lesser Franks, telling them what
> they should do to improve their sorry existences.
>
> This arrogant man needs to be humbled.
>
> "A standard commercial plays in the background. Orchestrated music
> swells into the booming voice of an announcer. 'The most successful
> man in the known universe has finally published his riveting life
> story. Learn the true story of Gossamer, Incorporated. Experience the
> dizzying ride of his life. And enjoy the perspective that only the
> great man himself can offer. FRANK JOHNSON, THE VIEW FROM THE CENTER.
> Now on sale at quality bookstores on a million enlightened earths!'